# По чтению бинарных данных

Tags: php

В таблице БД в одно из полей записаны параметры объекта в бинарном виде. Структура известна, примерно такова (представление на Делфи):

```
 type
    TMonPosition = packed  record

     Times:  double;   //8 
     EvTime: double;   //8 
     Format: single;   //4 
     Event:array[0..15] of longint;    // 4*16=64 
     Status:single;    //4 
     Status2:single;   //4 
 end;
```

Как эти данные можно было прочитать, используя php? Как получить параметры?

Comment: А что такое "таблица БД"?

Answer (score 1):

Прочитать - так же, как любое другое поле)

Получить поля - см. [(un)pack](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.unpack.php)

К сожалению, без бубна и интерпретатора под рукой точное решение не могу дать, что-то вроде

```
$dataArray = unpack('dTimes/dEvTime/lFormat/c8Event/lStatus/lStatus2', $row->myField);
```

- в этом вариант Event будет массивом char с ключами Event1 ... Event8
- при работе с pack и использовании double нужно учитывать параметры машины
- Естественно, того же результата можно добиться с помощью substr($row->myField, 0, 8) и приведением к int, но первый вариант - таки более правильный.